# How can I send a form via email?

Tags: html

I'm pretty new at HTML. I was wondering - how can you send an HTML form via email (client side) and have the recipient fill out the form in the email itself? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<a href="mailto:foo@example.org">Click here to open email client</a>
```

UPDATE:

You cannot send a form with client-side technologies. For this you will have to use a server-side language such as PHP; sending an HTML email. Moreover the form in the email will not be able to be filled out (like the way it's filled out on a webpage). You can have a link in the email where the user can fill-out a form on your site.

Comment: Please don't down vote correct answers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked (which is about sending an email containing an HTML form).

Answer (score 0):

An email is just an HTML content. Which your email client edits and shows you. So you can include anything to it, using HTML language, CSS, JS.

Here is what I tried:

```
<form>
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"something\" />
</form>
```

This was the part of the body element of the email and this generated an input field. Similarly, if I include submit buttons select statements they will also be added to the form.

The issue isn't how to add the form to the email, issue is will be user submit the form there? It is less secure this way! However, you **can** add form elements to the email. Good luck!

This is the image of the email.

[image]